# How to supress source command echo in tcl

Tags: tcl

It is mandatory i need to use source Init.tcl file, It produces some amount lines output to on my console, But I don't require the echo messages, i need suppress source information in my script.

Thanks
Malli

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963318/how-can-i-suppress-the-output-messages-of-tcl-procedures?rq=1

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate. Don't feel bad about the close vote. It doesn't indicate that you've done anything wrong. It's how the system is supposed to work - linking questions with the same answer together. It increases the probability of someone searching for this problem to get the correct answer. I've upvoted your question partly as consolation but also partly because I strongly believe that people should be encouraged to ask duplicate questions in order to improve the answer's searchability.